# java string to date conversion without seconds

Tags: java, date-conversion

I have to convert string to date such that it should throw error when string is having seconds. For example if I am giving input string as "2015-08-12 12:24:08" I should get an error because I am giving seconds in the string(i.e., 08 here), whereas if I give input as "2015-08-12 12:24" I shouldn't get any error. How can I achieve that?

I have tried below code

```
     String oldstring2 = "2015-08-12 12:24:08";
     Date date2 = null;
try {
    date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(oldstring2);
    System.out.println(date2);
    System.out.println("success");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("error");
}
```

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: If you just need to check if date is valid, you can do it based on a string length.

Comment: i tried something like `String oldstring2 = "2015-08-12 12:24";
    Date date2 = null;
     try {
         date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(oldstring2);
         System.out.println(date2);
         System.out.println("success");
     }
     catch (ParseException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("error");
     }`

Comment: From onwards please add your Code in your question

Comment: If you just want to check if string has seconds or not...check for colon(:) count. If there are two colon, date string is having seconds. and later you can convert to Date.

Comment: @peterremec using length is a good idea, but is there any other way?

Comment: @NagaRamaKrishna you can also make Calendar object with your string and check if seconds part is present.

Comment: @peterremec yea correct. i will try that.

Answer (score 4):

With Java 8 you can use the DateTimeFormatter class. Because this performs strict parsing instead of trying to match from the beginning like SimpleDateFormat does:

```
    String string = "2015-08-12 12:24";
    TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(string);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(ta);
```

the parse method will throw an Exception when you change string to include seconds:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-08-12 12:24:12' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateConversion {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS");
    Date d = sdf.parse("2015-08-12 12:24:08");
    System.out.println(d);

}

}
```

Comment: I am not getting any exception.

Comment: @NagaRama Krishna use SS in the sdf variable for being more specific so that if someone won't supply seconds it will throw error..

Comment: @NagaRama Krishna have it worked I've changed my answer edited, pleae try and confirm..

Comment: i dont want seconds to be accepted i chose to go with string length for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

```
String oldstring2 = "2015-08-12 12:24"; 
        String[] str = oldstring2.split(" ");
        if(str[1]!=null){
            String[] str2 = str[1].split(":");
            if(str2.length == 2)
                System.out.println("success");
            else
                System.out.println("error");
        }
```

If your input date is exactly like you specified every time, the above code would work.

Comment: we can do this way. but I am checking whether I can get exception at the time of parsing.

Comment: you can always create a custom exception class and throw new YourException() instead of printing error.

Answer (score -1):

The Regular expression can achieve the goal:

```
String oldstring2 = "2015-08-12 12:24";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^((\\d{2}(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))[\\-\\/\\s]?"
        + "((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\\-\\/\\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])))"
        + "|(((0?[469])|(11))[\\-\\/\\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30)))|"
        + "(0?2[\\-\\/\\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])))))|(\\d{2}(([02468][1235679])|"
        + "([13579][01345789]))[\\-\\/\\s]?((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\\-\\/\\s]?"
        + "((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\\-\\/\\s]?((0?[1-9])|"
        + "([1-2][0-9])|(30)))|(0?2[\\-\\/\\s]?((0?[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-8]))))))"
        + "(\\s(((0?[0-9])|([1-2][0-3]))\\:([0-5]?[0-9])()))?$");
if (p.matcher(oldstring2).matches()) {
    // do something
} else {
    // return the error
}
```